# Phaser game not loading

Tags: javascript, wampserver, phaser-framework

I am setting up a basic Phaser game, using WampServer, I have my project directory in the `www` directory of WampServer but it gives me the error that `SceneMainMenu is not defined` why and how can I fix this? Here are my files:

the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Space Shooter</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="phaser.js"></script>
  <script src="/scenes/SceneMain.js"></script>
  <script src="/scenes/SceneMainMenu.js"></script>
  <script src="/scenes/SceneGameOver.js"></script>
  <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the game.js

```
var config = {
  type: Phaser.WEBGL,
  width: 400,
  height:640,
  backgroundColor: 'black',
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: {y: 0}
    }
  },
  scene: [
    SceneMainMenu,
    SceneMain,
    SceneGameOver
  ],
  pixelArt: true,
  roundPixels: true
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

SceneGameOVer file:

```
class SceneGameOver extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({key:'SceneGameOver'})
  }
}
```

SceneMain file:

```
class SceneMain extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({key:'sceneMain'});
  }
}
```

SceneMainMenu file:

```
class SceneMainMenu extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({key: 'SceneMainMenu'});
  }
  create() {
    this.scene.start('SceneMain');
  }
}
```

If I am running the game from VS code's server it runs, but when I try to launch it from WampServer it gives me this error

Comment: Is all your js loaded successfully?

Comment: only the game.js for the rest I get the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), why do they fail to load?

Comment: Where is `SceneMain.js` located?

Comment: in a scenes folder.

Comment: For some reason WampServer doesn't load some files, but I can't figure out why

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer:
After re-read your code, I found the possible cause of the scene not loading might be that the scenes are not active. For details about how to launch a multiple-scene game, please go through this tutorial posted by Richard Davey: https://phaser.io/phaser3/devlog/121

As a short answer, in each scene constructor, you can call

```
super({key: 'YourSceneKey', active: true}
```

to activate the scene when the game was created.
Here is a example codePen that I created for your reference
https://codepen.io/arthurcen/pen/yZyaNX

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22002107)

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I updated my answer which gives a more detailed solution.